# aggregate data based on ID and groupID observations

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hey i have data such as:

```
id       cashpayment     total payment   groupID
1        30.00              100.00           A
1        30.00              100.00           B
1        30.00              100.00           C
1        40.00              100.00           B
2        25.00              400.00           C
2        20.00              300.00           C
2        35.00              200.00           B
3        40.00              200.00           B
```

I want to aggregate cahspayment and total payment so that result looks like the following:

```
id       cashpayment     total payment   
1        130.00             400.00           
2        80.00              900.00          
3        40.00               200.00
```

Separately, I want to the same thing, but with groupID taken into account so I will get the following

```
id       cashpayment     total payment   groupID
1        30.00              100.00           A
1        70.00              200.00           B
1        30.00              100.00           C
2        45.00              700.00           C
2        35.00              200.00           B
3        40.00              200.00           B
```

In both case I need this to be put into a new table

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, sum(cashpayment), sum([total payment])
from table 
group by id
order by ID
```

for the first and

```
   select id, sum(cashpayment), sum([total payment]), groupID
    from table 
    group by id, groupID
    order by id,groupid
```

for the second

Comment: i tried an into statement in the line before the from statement and it will not allow me to make a new table

Comment: Sure it will but seeing as you haven't shown any table definitions, test data or your attempt at solving your problems (and any associated errors) you're not really  making it easy for people to help you.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx